# Dealing with "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" error in Percona Server

Tags: database, deadlock, timeout

I recently upgraded our magento 1.7 database server from `MySQL 5.4` to `Percona 5.6` in the interest of performance.

As expected, the site and general performance of magento has increased vastly, but at the cost of these errors occurring more frequently than before:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

So, I begun a research into this error & issue and it has been frequently discussed. One point that interests me are the following:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/

By default, percona uses `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.
However, during my research there has been numerous recommendation (for e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799980/2332336) that favours `READ_COMMITED` isolation level combined with `binlog-format = ROW` over the default.

I wanted to ask; if I were to change the percona server's isolation level as per recommendation, are there any serious implications? Like, will it work? Will it help? Will it break magento?

The changes I am considering for the percona56 are the following:

- isolation-level = READ_COMMITED
- binlog-format = ROW
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120 (currently default value 50)

Should I also be considering other changes to prevent these lock wait timeout errors?

P.S. the magento has a cron job that runs every 15 minutes to load stock level/product updates from a FTP server (third party warehouse software) and imports it into magento, I believe this is what's causing the timeout (and sometimes deadlocks) to occur.

Comment: Hello from the future :-) I'm dealing with the same problem with Magento 1.9 and Percona 5.7. I'm also reasearching side-effects of `isolation-level = READ_COMMITED` and `binlog-format = ROW`. Did you try it? any problem? actually fixed or not? thanks!